# Clear Div then insert new content

Tags: javascript, html

I have a script that take data from an input box, then displays it to

```
messageBox.innerHTML += "Title: " + titles + "<br/>";
```

If the user types in the box again, how can i clear the div and re add the new text to messageBox?

I tried to use in a function then call the function but it doesn't work:

```
 var element = document.getElementById("display");
 element.outerHTML = "";
 delete element;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The use of `innerHTML +=` is appending the new content. Remove the + which will make it an assignment, and will cause the old content to be overwritten and lost, leaving just the new content.

```
messageBox.innerHTML = "Title: " + titles + "<br/>";
//                   ^ no plus
```

Comment: wow, really that is all it was! Thanks MrCode! It works now. I was confusing myself.

Comment: I added another
 
    messageBox.innerHTML = "ID: " + id + "<br/>";
    messageBox.innerHTML += "Title: " + titles + "<br/>";

 One clear but the other does not. Am I missing something?

Comment: It looks like you have the `+=` in the second one, change to just `=`

Comment: Sorry I missed typed, messageBox.innerHTML = "ID: " + id + "<br/>"; messageBox.innerHTML = "Title: " + titles + "<br/>"; is the corrected way.

Answer (score 1):

Simply change this

```
messageBox.innerHTML += "Title: " + titles + "<br/>";
```

to this

```
messageBox.innerHTML = "Title: " + titles + "<br/>";
```

The `+=` adds the html to the previous html. Using `=` replaces all the html in messageBox with the new input.